# KQL script to retrieve information from Azure VM

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, kql

I'm working on a KQL script to retrieve all kind of information from a Azure VM, what I would like to retrieve is:

- Name
- Location
- Resource Group
- Subscription
- VMSize
- Private IP address

Most of them are working fine in below script, however, now I want to add the CPU and memory information to this list. Is there a way that I can extract those 2 out of the vmSize information? Or is there any other way?

```
resources
| where type == "microsoft.compute/virtualmachines"
| join kind=leftouter (resourcecontainers | where type == "microsoft.resources/subscriptions" | project subscription = name, subscriptionId) on subscriptionId
| extend nicId = tostring(properties.networkProfile.networkInterfaces[0].id)
| join kind=leftouter (resources | where type == 'microsoft.network/networkinterfaces' | project nicId = id, privateIPAllocation = properties.ipConfigurations[0].properties.privateIPAllocationMethod, privateIPAddress = properties.ipConfigurations[0].properties.privateIPAddress) on nicId
| project name, subscription, resourceGroup, location, zones, properties.provisioningState, properties.hardwareProfile.vmSize, properties.extended.instanceView.osName, properties.extended.instanceView.osVersion, properties.extended.instanceView.powerState.displayStatus, properties.licenseType, nicId, privateIPAllocation, privateIPAddress
```

From all tests that I've performed the CPU and memory information remains empty or returns null

[Result from script]
[image]

Comment: Could you post source example record(s) too please?  Of course please feel free to remove any sensitive information.

Comment: @GyptheCat, I've added the result. It is the intention to have next to the vmSize column, as well the information for CPU and memory

Comment: Hi @JorisWillekens, Check this `KQL Query` to display the `VM` information. Here is the [result](https://i.imgur.com/gM1qhk1.png)

    VMComputer
    | project DisplayName, AzureLocation, AzureResourceGroup, PhysicalMemoryMB,Cpus,Ipv4Addresses

Comment: Hi @VenkatV, thx, however when I try to execute it in the Azure Resource Graph Explorer, is mentions that table VMComputer is invalid, unsupported or disallowed.

Comment: Hi @JorisWillekens,   You can run the same query in **Log Analytics** instead of **Azure Resource Graph Explorer**.

Comment: Hi @VenkatV, strange thing is that I don't see any results in the Log Analytics.

Comment: Can I post the solution with detailed steps, how to fetch VM details using KQL query in Log Analytics?

Comment: Yes please, would be good to see how you are doing that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> KQL script to retrieve information from Azure VM

Here are the steps to retrieve the **VM** information using **KQL Log Query**.

1. Create a **Log Analytics Work Space**
2. Go to **Monitor**  in the Azure portal, select **Virtual Machines** > **Not monitored** and select your **VM** > **Enable** > select your existing **Log Analytics Work Space**.

[image]

3. After completing the deployment, wait for some time for the data to be sent to **Log Analytics Work Space**.
4. Go to **Log Analytics Work Space** and select **Logs**. Then run the following **KQL** query.

```
VMComputer
| project DisplayName, AzureLocation, AzureResourceGroup, PhysicalMemoryMB,Cpus,Ipv4Addresses
```

**Here is the result**

[image]